# Groovy script to break payload for every date between start and end dates

Tags: date, groovy, date-difference, groovyscriptengine

I have an input like this:

```
<root>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc10</loc_name>
    <points>3</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-11T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-13T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc 11</loc_name>
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-16T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
</root>
```

I want to duplicate the data for every day between start and end date.
Want to have an output like:

```
<root>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc10</loc_name>
    <points>3</points>
    <Date>2023-09-11T22:39:40Z</Date>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc10</loc_name>
    <points>3</points>
    <Date>2023-09-12T22:39:40Z</Date>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc10</loc_name>
    <points>3</points>
    <Date>2023-09-13T22:39:40Z</Date>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc11</loc_name>
    <point>4</points>
    <Date>2023-09-16T22:39:40Z</Date>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc11</loc_name>
    <point>4</points>
    <Date>2023-09-17T22:39:40Z</Date>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc11</loc_name>
    <point>4</points>
    <Date>2023-09-18T22:39:40Z</Date>
  </results>
</root>
```

How can we do this in groovy?

I am unable to find any examples on how to loop over the payload and create this new payload in Groovy

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stackoverflow isn't really a code writing service

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick script that does what you are looking for:

```
import java.text.*
import groovy.xml.*

def text = '''
<root>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 10</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc10</loc_name>
    <points>3</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-11T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-13T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
  <results>
    <loc>Loc 11</loc>
    <loc_name>Loc Desc 11</loc_name>
    <points>4</points>
    <StartDate>2023-09-16T22:39:40Z</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2023-09-18T22:45:36.437000Z</EndDate>
  </results>
</root>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( text )
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
SimpleDateFormat endParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
def output = new XmlParser().parseText("<root/>")

xml.results.each { resXml ->
   Date startDate = parser.parse( resXml.StartDate.text() )
   Date endDate = endParser.parse( resXml.EndDate.text() )
   
   Date currentDate = new Date( startDate.time )
   while( currentDate < endDate ) {
       Node resultsNode = output.appendNode( new QName("results"), [:] )
       resXml.children().findAll { child -> child.name() != "StartDate" && child.name() != "EndDate" }.each { child ->
          resultsNode.appendNode( new QName(child.name()), [:], child.text() )
       }
       resultsNode.appendNode(new QName("Date"), [:], parser.format( currentDate ))
       currentDate = currentDate + 1
   }
}
println( XmlUtil.serialize(output ) )
```

A few things I noticed and should explain.  The `StartDate` node and `EndDate` nodes have different date formats.  Seems strange.  You might want to clean that up if you control the generation of this XML.

The trick is that `parseText` returns a `GPathResult` which allows you to execute queries across the xml nodes (ie `xml.results.each` to iterate over the nodes under the root element).  You also have access to the groovy collection methods (ie `findAll`, `collect`, `each`, etc).  So the loop used to copy the nodes from the input document into the output uses `findAll` to filter it all nodes that aren't `StartDate` or `EndDate` the iterates that set using `each`.